# Why can't my Django root url-conf find my app module?

Tags: python, django, configuration

I'm wondering if someone can help me. I am looking to restructure a new django project, to represent the below:

```
-repository/ 
       -config/
           -asgi.py
           -settings.py
           -urls.py
           -wsgi.py
           -__init__.py
       -project root/
           -app_1/
               -admin.py
               -apps.py
               -models.py
               -tests.py
               -urls.py
               -views.py
               -__init__.py
           -app_2/
               -...
           -app_3/
               -...
           -migrations/
               -__init__.py
           -static/
           -templates/
       -docs/
       -manage.py
```

I have tried to implement this so far by appending the below lines to the settings.py file:

```
# This is the <repository root>
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# This is the <project repository>
PROJECT_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'project'

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT / 'media'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT / 'static_root'
STATIC_URL = PROJECT_ROOT / 'static'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

Templates = [{ ...
'DIRS': [PROJECT_ROOT / 'templates'],
... }]
```

In the installed apps I have to specify '.app1' vs traditionally just 'app1'. I amended the manage.py,wsgi.py,asgi.py file etc to point to the settings file.

**However...**

When I try to include() an app specific urlconf in the config root urlconf using the below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import project.app1

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='app1'))
]
```

it says

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app1'"

Please can someone advise if i am missing a step in this restructue and/or if i'm missing something in the url conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add some subdirectory (`project_root`) to your app without add `__init__.py`. Django can't found your `app1` path.

Try to register `subdirectory` to your Django path in `settings.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_root'))
```

Suggestion: Do not use whitespace to your Django module/directory

Answer (score 0):

Add `app1` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`